# XML to json conversion, in Java, while preserving the data types

Tags: java, xml, json

I am using `org.json api` to convert xml to json. The problem is certain tags in my xml contain non string values (i.e., int, boolean, double etc...).

The code I am using below, is successfully converting xml to json, but the primitive data types are converted to string in the json response. For eg: `<age>10<age>` in xml gets converted to `{"age" : "10" }` in which the value `10` in json is a `String` which should be an `Integer`. For example `{"age" : 10 }`.

The xml input which I give for conversion, is dynamic and will change frequently. But for the sake of showing it as an example, I am saving the xml as a `String`. The dynamically generated xml code will be saved in a string variable.

Can anyone help me out in converting the xml to json, while preserving the data types? Below is the code

```
import org.json.*;
public class XmlToJson {
     private static String xmlCode = 
                     "<handler>
                         <price>10</price>
                         <item>rice</item>
                         <VALUE>3434</VALUE>
                     </handler>
                     <flow>
                     </flow>";
         public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException{
               JSONObject xmlJsonObj=null;
               xmlJsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlCode);
               System.out.println(xmlJsonObj.toString(1));
         }
}
```

*Sample output:*

```
{
    "flow": "",
    "handler": {
        "VALUE": "3434",
        "item": "rice",
        "price": "10"
    }
}
```

*The expected behavior is:*

```
{
    "flow": "",
    "handler": {
        "VALUE": 3434,
        "item": "rice",
        "price": 10
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how the code could know `10` is an int and not a string

Comment: I understand. But is there any way to parse over the converted json to search for primitive data types and convert them back to its original type? My requirement is that... :-)

Comment: I bail out of trying to format that, that's 2 times you overwrite the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at my open source library [unXml](https://github.com/tajakobsen/unxml), which parses xml, and outputs Json. It's written for Java 8, and uses the (awesome) [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) Json-library.

[UnXml](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.nerdforge%22) is available on Maven Central.

*Given this xml (Added a root to make wellformed)*

```
<root>
    <handler>
        <price>10</price>
        <item>rice</item>
        <VALUE>3434</VALUE>
    </handler>
    <flow></flow>
</root>
```

*You create a parser like this*

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.Parsing;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.factory.ParsingFactory;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.parsers.Parser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class XmlParser {
    public ObjectNode parseXml(String inputXml){
        Parsing parsing = ParsingFactory.getInstance().create();
        Document document = parsing.xml().document(inputXml);

        Parser<ObjectNode> parser = parsing.obj("root")
            .attribute("flow")
            .attribute("handler",  "handler", parsing.obj()
                .attribute("price", "price", parsing.number())
                .attribute("item")
                .attribute("value", "VALUE", parsing.with(Integer::parseInt))
            )
            .build();

        ObjectNode result = parser.apply(document);
        return result;
    }
}
```

*Which will return this Json*

```
{
    "handler":{
        "item":"rice",
        "price":10.0,
        "value":3434
    },
    "flow":""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your schema is set, you can go through databinding  with POJOs ( convert XML into JSOs, 
convert POJOs to JSON )  - there is a lot of databinding tools  and I would recomment those working on  top of pull-model ( XStream for XML,   GSON for JSON - but there is a rich choice
to pich your favorite )

If you are better on XML side, you can also write XSLT transformation which will convert XML to whatever you like , also JSON - though I personally find JavaBeans way easier

Answer (score 0):

I second Konstantin's suggestion of using POJOs in-between XML and JSON -- otherwise you will be having endless problems due to mismatch between the two. Specifically, XML has "native" way of expressing arrays/Lists, so handling of empty and single-element lists/arrays typically produces odd results.

My suggestion would be to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) for JSON and either [JAXB](http://jaxb.dev.java.net) or [Jackson XML-data-binding](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-xml-databind) for XML -- that way you can also use JAXB annotations for extra information, if naming has to be changed or so.

And whatever else you use, dump org.json package; alternatives are better nowadays so that package serves mostly as historical relic (it was useful when alternatives weren't around).